# Несколько форм поиска по сайту на одной странице

Tags: wordpress, форма

Несколько форм поиска по сайту на одной странице. Совпадают ID, что не валидно На странице поиска дизайнер с заказчиком решили вывести поисковую форму не только в хедере, но и в контетной области. Естественно ID у них одинаковый. Как решить вопрос с валидностью?

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того как программно выводится эта форма.

1. Можно изменить id на class и в css файле поправить # на .
2. Можно прописать разные id для форм.

После уточнения способа вывода формы смогу подсказать более конкретно.
При этом все будет валидно и сохранятся стили оформления.

Comment: Ну я решил вопрос, тем что сменил id на класс, но интересно как решать вопрос, если нужно было бы дописывать id и выводить форму несколько раз на странице?

Comment: Тогда придется продублировать стили в css.
Например: есть 2 формы с ид "id1" и "id2".
В css прописаны стили для первой формы например input#id1 {padding: 10px; }, делаем дубль. input#id1, input#id2 {padding: 10px; }. Вот и делов-то =)